# Reading a pdf file created using iText in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, fileinputstream

I am using iText libraries to create pdf files using java, the file is created and it opens up using adobe, but when I try to read it i get java.io.FileNotFoundException: ErRecord.pdf (The system cannot find the file specified)

```
FileInputStream input = null;
File file = new File("ErRecord.pdf");
System.out.println(file.canRead());
input = new FileInputStream(file);
```

file.canRead() returns false, is there a way to read the file or make it readable using iText?

Comment: Are you sure that the path to `ErRecord.pdf` is correct? Please check this by putting something like "test.txt" in the same directory. Can you read that file? If not, you are making the wrong assumptions about the location of your JVM's working directory. There is no reason why an iText generated PDF can't be read into a `File` object.

Answer (score 1):

I used getAbsoluteFile() and the path was wrong..
I just used the absolute path

File file = new File("c:/Users/rawan/workspace-luna/Prototype_3/ErRecord.pdf");

and it worked just fine